# Yii2 - Two models in one form - Values are not saved in the second model

Tags: yii2

I have a model called Patientinformation.php and a model called AlternativeInformation.php. I would like to use the two models in the patientinformation_form.php

Patientinformation model: 
- id (PK)  
- patient_id 
- patient_initials 
- collection_site 
- cancer 
- study (FK to study model)

AlternativeInformation model: 
- alternative_id (PK) 
- patients_patient_id (FK to id of the Patientinformation model) 
- alternative_study (FK to study model) 
- alternative_patient_id

I have updated the Patientinformation controller as well as the create.php file and the _form.php file.

If I enter values in the Patientinformation form.php, I am redirected to the Patientinformation view site. The values of the Patientinformation model (id, patient_id, patient_initials, collection_site, cancer and study) are saved in the database. 
 
 **However, the values of the AlternativeInformation model (alternative_study and alternative_patient_id) are not saved in the database.**

This is the **PatientinformationController.php** file:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Patientinformation;
use app\models\AlternativeInformation;
use app\models\PatientinformationSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

    /**
     * Creates a new Patientinformation model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Patientinformation();
        $modelAlternative = new AlternativeInformation();     


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelAlternative->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            $model->save();
            $modelAlternative->patients_patient_id = $model->id;
            $modelAlternative->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelAlternative' => $modelAlternative,
        ]);
    }
```

This is the **create.php** file:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Patientinformation */
/* @var $modelAlternative app\models\AlternativeInformation */


$this->title = 'Add patient';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Patients', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="patientinformation-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelAlternative' => $modelAlternative,

    ]) ?>

</div>
```

And this is the **_form.php** file:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\CollectionSiteInformation;
use app\models\AlternativeInformation;
use app\models\StudyInformation;
use app\models\CancerInformation;
use unclead\multipleinput\MultipleInput;
use kartik\select2\Select2;



/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Patientinformation */
/* @var $modelAlternative app\models\AlternativeInformation */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="patientinformation-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <p>
    Please note that all fields marked with an asterisk (<font color="red">*</font>) are required.
    </p>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'study')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(StudyInformation::find()->all(),'id','study'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Please select a study'],
        ]); 
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'patient_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'patient_initials')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'collection_site')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(CollectionSiteInformation::find()->all(),'id','collection_site'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Please select a collection site'],
        ]); 
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'cancer')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(CancerInformation::find()->all(),'id','cancer'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Please select a cancer type'],
        ]); 
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($modelAlternative,'alternative_study')->widget(MultipleInput::class,[
    'max' => 6,
    'allowEmptyList'    => false,
    'enableGuessTitle'  => true,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'name'  => 'alternative_study',
            'type'  => 'dropDownList',
            'title' => 'Alternative Study',
            'items' => ArrayHelper::map(studyInformation::find()->asArray()->all (),'id','study'),
            'options' => ['prompt' => 'Please select an alternative study if applicable'],
        ],
    ]
    ])
    ->label(false);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($modelAlternative,'alternative_patient_id')->widget(MultipleInput::class,[
        'max' => 6,
        'allowEmptyList'    => false,
        'enableGuessTitle'  => true,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'name'  => 'alternative_patient_id',
                'title' => 'Alternative patient ID',
                'options' => ['prompt' => 'Please select an alternative study if applicable'],
            ],
        ]
        ])
        ->label(false);
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

If I don`t use unclead\multipleinput\MultipleInput in my _form.php, all the values of AlternativeInformation model (alternative_study and alternative_patient_id) are saved into the model/database.

**So I assume that I don`t pass any items to the MultipleInput widget.**

This is the AlternativeInformation model file:

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['patients_patient_id', 'alternative_study'], 'required'],
            [['patients_patient_id', 'alternative_study'], 'integer'],
            [['alternative_patient_id'], 'string', 'max' => 265],
            [['patients_patient_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => PatientInformation::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['patients_patient_id' => 'id']],
            [['alternative_study'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => StudyInformation::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['alternative_study' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'alternative_id' => 'Alternative ID',
            'patients_patient_id' => 'Patients Patient ID',
            'alternative_study' => 'Alternative Study',
            'alternative_patient_id' => 'Alternative Patient ID',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPatientsPatient()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PatientInformation::className(), ['id' => 'patients_patient_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAlternativeStudy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StudyInformation::className(), ['id' => 'alternative_study']);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how this issue can be solved? How will be the values of "alternative_study" and "alternative_patient_id" saved into the AlternativeInformation model if using the MultipleInput widget?

I really need the option in the form to enter no, one or several alternative studies as well as alternative patient ids.

I really appreciate any help how I can solve this issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: This seems more like a database design problem than related to Yii, it seems like you have modeled the relations as 1-1 when, based on what you are saying, the relation is 1-*. In that case you should start by refactoring your database to model the data relation properly, after that you can change your code. The controller should save * instances of AlternativeStudy and AlternativePatientInformation.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting some validation errors that you can't see because you are redirecting to the `view` action even if the `AlternativeInformation` model has validation errors.

The first step towards finding a solution would be making sure that, if `AlternativeInformation` doesn't save you show the form again, that way you will see the validation errors.

Update your controller code to this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Patientinformation();
    $modelAlternative = new AlternativeInformation();     


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) 
        && $modelAlternative->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
        && $model->save()) {

        $modelAlternative->patients_patient_id = $model->id;

        if ($modelAlternative->save()) {

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelAlternative' => $modelAlternative,
    ]);
}
```

That should help you find the problem, it will also give your users information about any future errors that may happen.

The validation problem may be on `alternative_patient_id`, it seems that you are not passing any `items` to the `MultipleInput` widget.

Comment: Hi Raul. Thanks for your answer. I have updated my controller code like you`ve suggested. Now, I get two **errors** in the form: **"Alternative study must be an integer"** and **"Alternative Patient ID must be a string"**

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller with the following code.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Patientinformation();
        $modelAlternative = new AlternativeInformation();     


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&    $modelAlternative->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            if($model->save()){
                $modelAlternative->patients_patient_id = $model->id;
                $modelAlternative->save();
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelAlternative' => $modelAlternative,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: This code will redirect to the `view` action even if `$modelAlternative->save()` fails validation, could you explain why you think this code is better than the one I posted earlier?

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion didn`t help me to find a solution. I am redirected to the view site but the values of the AlternativeInformation model are not saved.